# Set String value to Variable based on cell in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple question that should be simple to answer.  I am trying to make a string reflect the value of a cell. The naming scheme of the spreadsheet that it will import is the value of "(CSV) & ("[1].csv") with no space.  CSV is the value of B5.  If the variable CSV = WASHINGTON I need the line to read

```
Windows(WASHINGTON[1].csv).Activate
```

Below is what I have.  I am having an error with the CSV Variable.

```
Sub Import_CSV()

Import_CSV Macro

    Dim CSV As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Windows("Records.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    CSV = Cells(5, "B").Value
    Windows(CSV & "[1].csv").Activate
    Rows("1:2").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Cut ... etc
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *What is my error?*  WHy don't you tell us what the error is, and then perhaps we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: You have declared `CSV As Long` but you are expecting a `String` data type. That will almost certainly raise a mismatch error for any non-numeric value.

Comment: Very true.  I did not phrase that good at all.  I apologize for that.

Found a site that answered my question :

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/vba-for-dummies-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `CSV As Long` but you are expecting a `String` data type. That will almost certainly raise a mismatch error for any non-numeric value.

Declare `Dim CSV as String` and that should resolve it.

Note: This assumes that the specified file is already open.  If not, you will get an error on the `.Activate` statement.

You should also avoid using `Activate` and `Select` methods. There are some resources on here that explain why:

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Please, in the future do a better job describing what your actual problem is -- if you get an eerror message, indicate what that message is, and on which line it raises.  This is *very* helpful for others who are trying to assist you.